# How to distinguish good sense from usual sense (are both common sense?)

Tags: ambiguity, portuguese

In Portuguese, we have different expressions that are both translated into English "common sense":

"Bom senso" - What one have when is a sensible, wise, sagacious person.

"Senso comum" - The common view of the general public, sometimes wise ("Vox Populi, Vox Dei"), but sometimes mislead by propaganda, anger, hunger, etc.

In English, how can we distinguish these two meanings, or all we have is "common sense" to mean both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the fixed expression **received wisdom**.

> **received** adj.
>
> Having been accepted as true or worthy, especially without firsthand
>   corroboration:
>
> "the received wisdom that attributes academic success or failure to
>   natural aptitudes" (Jerome Karabel).

[[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/received)]

> **received wisdom**: knowledge or information that people generally believe is true ...

[[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+received+wisdom)]

A fairly recent alternative is **conventional wisdom**

> the body of ideas or explanations generally accepted as true by the
>   public and/or by experts in a field.

(see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_wisdom)).

*Common sense* has your 'bom senso' meaning.